# ui:inputDate updating error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, date, date-picker

```
<aura:attribute name="dueDate" type="Date"/>
<aura:attribute name="dueDateString" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.dueDate}" action="{!c.dueDateChanged}"/>

<ui:inputDate aura:id="dueDateField" format="MMM d, YYYY" displayDatePicker="true" value="{! v.dueDate }"/>
```

Controller

```
dueDateChanged: function(component) {
        var dueDate = component.get("v.dueDate");
        if (dueDate) {
            component.set("v.dueDateString", $A.localizationService.formatDate(dueDate) );
        } else {
            component.set("v.dueDateString", '');
        }
        console.log( 'dueDateString: ', component.get("v.dueDateString") );
    },
```

The first time when I set the date there is no issue but when I can change the date again, I run into the below issue:

> Uncaught Action failed: ui:datePickerGrid$controller$dateCellSelected
>   [dateCellCmp.updateCell is not a function]

Comment: Can you post your controller and/or helper code?

Comment: I dont get any errors with the code you posted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thanks, it works as it is. But when the dueDate & dueDateString are in a aura:renderIf the above mentioned error arises... but I changed aura:renderIf to div classes.. and then everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the issue occurs due to the date format you are providing and the date format you are trying to set, both formats should be same, so i did the following changes in my code, Please refer it.

```
**Component**
<aura:attribute name="visitDate" type="String"/>

<ui:inputDate aura:id="Wellness Visit"  format="MM/dd/yyyy" value="{!v.visitDate}"  displayDatePicker="true" class="inpText"/>

**Helper**
//Function for formating date in MM/dd/yyyy format
toDateFormat: function(val) {
        debugger;

        if(val != undefined && val != '') {
            var dateTimeParts = val.split(' ');
            console.log('****dateTimeParts'+dateTimeParts);
            var dtParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('/');
            var obj = (dtParts[0].length == 1 ? '0'+dtParts[0] : dtParts[0])+'/'+(dtParts[1].length == 1 ? '0'+dtParts[1] : dtParts[1]) + '/' + dtParts[2]; 
            return obj;
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }

//Getting values from apex controller and set visit date
component.set("v.visitDate", helper.toDateFormat(myobj.visit_date__c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ui:Input date , and no other ui: components, they will be soon deprecated !

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm

Instead, you can use lightning:input using date type , using only date attribute and not string attribute for the value